# SSL certificate and domains

Tags: ssl, configuration, domain, ssl-certificate

I have a web service on address example.com and I add some functionality to it using completly separate web application set on different host. I want to set a subdomain another.example.com to open my new application. So by now I have two host providers and another one who maintain my domain.

I want another.example.com to be encrypted: https://another.example.com. So I need to buy a certificate and install it. What do I need to do? Where it should be installed? Which server should be configured to use it? My second host provider or that with domain? Do I need to reconfigure my domain?

Can someone explain it to me? I'm a little bit confused right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the server with the ssl endpoint has to hold the certificate. When your server another.example.com is directly accessed, than you have to install the certificate on this server. When your webserver example.com acts as reverse proxy (all request go through this server) to another.example.com, than you have to install the certificate on this server.

I hope this clarifies the issue.